# QR Hiring system

Tags: qr-code

Need direct to find the best platform that can build this.

I’m looking to create a QR seniority based hiring system. We have 700 employees that hire out by seniority and certification requirements. I’m looking to stream line the process using QR codes. Currently we do it manually with pen and paper. The time is starting to add up on larger hires and take too long.

Example 1 : Hire two 25 man gangs for a RoRo. They all need to have hazmat, longshoreman skills & RoRo driver certifications. If they have all certs then they can choose to take the job. I would like the system to limit the hire out to 25 per gang. So we don’t over hire by accident.

Example 2 : Hire out for a break bulk boat. We need 2 crane operators, 4 guys in the hole, 4 guys on the dock, 4 guys in the yard, 1 van driver, 3 heavy lift operators & 2 truck drivers.
In this example we need to be able to select the job the worker chooses and input their QR scan there.

Example 3 : Hire 75 porters, 10 stores, 10 sorters & 9 pushers.
In this example we need to be able to select the job the worker chooses and input their QR scan there.

I would like to have the option to delete workers from hire sheet if an emergency happens and they can no longer take the job.

I’d like the system to print out a hire slip with the workers name, work number & some other info we input ourselves. We have a variety of jobs we hire for daily and weekly. So the system has to some UI that we control and input information into per job / hire

Above would be stage one.
Stage two would link to certification spreadsheet adding features.

The certifications part would need to link to a spreadsheet that updates monthly. Workers can loose certifications so they wouldn’t be eligible to be hired on some jobs. We need a developer to help set up the bones and we can manage the daily tasks.

Addition options:
For replacements for workers who want to quit half way through the job. Would be nice to automate that part of the system as well. Here it could be we use a QR code to scan info in or manually put in the workers info if they aren’t present. We’d need to print a hard copy and be able to send copies/ screen shots via text.

A blank field for notes per worker would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome BCILA!  If you're looking for a developer to write your software, I'm sorry, but that's not what we offer here.  We help people find existing software to meet their needs.  Please clarify your question to request the latter, or delete your question if you are only looking to hire a developer.  Thanks, and regardless, welcome!

Comment: Are you looking for an end-user product to facilitate all this, or for components you can use to construct it?

Comment: Looking for anny advice on the best way to build it. If there are systems out there I can use that would be amazing. If I need to build from scratch that’s fine too. Appreciate the advice